# Centering GWT Button inside div

Tags: button, gwt, alignment

Help me please to centering GWT Button inside div

**Code**

```
<div class='{style.container}'>
    <g:Button addStyleNames='{style.styleAlign}'>Click</g:Button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            vertical-align: middle;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
.styleAlign {
            font-size: 17px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            height: 60px;
            width: 500px;
        }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this:

```
.container { 
    text-align: center; 
}
```